# received error: tornado.ioloop.TimeoutError: Operation timed out after 5 seconds.what to do?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

Hy. I try to write test for webHander:

```
import pytest
import tornado
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
import urllib.parse


class TestRESTAuthHandler(AsyncTestCase):
@tornado.testing.gen_test
def test_http_fetch_login(self):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(dict(username='admin', password='123456'))
    client = AsyncHTTPClient(self.io_loop)
    response = yield client.fetch("http://localhost:8080//#/login", method="POST", body=data)
    # Test contents of response
    self.assertIn("Automation web console", response.body)
```

Received error when running test:

raise TimeoutError('Operation timed out after %s seconds' % timeout)

tornado.ioloop.TimeoutError: Operation timed out after 5 seconds

Comment: Is there an HTTP server listening on localhost port 8080? Does it respond?

Comment: no. I am new in it .how to do it? and maybe I should start tornado server here? I think something missing in test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AsyncHTTPTestCase, not just AsyncTestCase. A nice example is in Tornado's self-tests:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/d7d9c467cda38f4c9352172ba7411edc29a85196/tornado/test/httpclient_test.py#L130-L130

You need to implement `get_app` to return an application with the RequestHandler you've written. Then, do something like:

```
class TestRESTAuthHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        # implement this
        pass

    def test_http_fetch_login(self):
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(dict(username='admin', password='123456'))
        response = self.fetch("http://localhost:8080//#/login", method="POST", body=data)
        # Test contents of response
        self.assertIn("Automation web console", response.body)
```

AsyncHTTPTestCase provides convenient features so you don't need to write coroutines with "gen.coroutine" and "yield".

Also, I notice you're fetching a url with a fragment after "#", please note that in real life web browsers do not include the fragment when they send the URL to the server. So your server would see the URL only as "//", not "//#/login".

Answer (score 4):

Set `ASYNC_TEST_TIMEOUT` environment variable.

> Runs the IOLoop until stop is called or timeout has passed.
>
> In the event of a timeout, an exception will be thrown. The default timeout is 5 seconds; it may be overridden with a timeout keyword argument or globally with the ASYNC_TEST_TIMEOUT environment variable. -- from http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase.wait

Comment: Worked fine! Thanks!